# Properly synchronized C++ code

Tags: c++, synchronized

I was given a question some time ago that I am not sure of how to answer, the question is typed below: can anyone give me an idea of how i should go about doing this using C++

write code to help synchronize a professor and his/her students during office hours. The professor, of course, wants to take a nap if no students are around to ask questions; if there are students who want to ask questions, they must synchronize with each other and with the professor so that
only one person is speaking at any one time,
each student question is answered by the professor, and
no student asks another question before the professor is done answering the previous one.
You are to write four procedures: AnswerStart(), AnswerDone(), QuestionStart() , and QuestionDone().
The professor loops running the code: AnswerStart(); give answer; AnswerDone(). AnswerStart doesn't return until a question has been asked. Each student loops running the code: QuestionStart(); ask question; QuestionDone(). QuestionStart() does not return until it is the student's turn to ask a question. Since professors consider it rude for a student not to wait for an answer, QuestionEnd() should not return until the professor has finished answering the question.

Comment: Multithreading and thread synchronization are not implemented in standard C++; that is done using OS-specific libraries. In which OS are you doing this? (just in case; OS = Operating System)

Comment: @dario_ramos: they are now; C++11 has a standardised memory model, and a thread support library.

Comment: @Mike: I'm pretty sure the OP is using an older standard (since he tagged his post C++ and not C++11), but anyway, it's good to let him know that. +1.

Comment: @MikeSeymour My compiler doesn't support C++11 threads yet... :/ At least we have boost.

Comment: Boost.Thread is pretty close to what's coming in C++ soon - http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/thread.html

Comment: I'm using the Linux OS (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

[Readers/Writer locks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers-writer_lock) might be what you are looking for.

This sounds like a homework question, as per the [community guidelines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) can you let us know what you've tried?

Comment: I was thinking about using a data structure to organize each question, so to mimic a first come first serve algorithm, thanks for the link

Comment: You are on the right track with the queue, you probably just need a semaphore or monitor to keep race conditions from happening. This basically rewords your problem and gives a few pseudocode solutions: [Producer/Consumer Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem#Using_monitors)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming this is a class assignment so I won't give away the answer.

I would handle this with an **active object**.

Comment: I was being vague on purpose, Herb Sutter:
http://drdobbs.com/go-parallel/article/showArticle.jhtml?articleID=225700095

Answer (score 1):

you are going to have to have serialized access to variables and use locks to make sure multiple actions are not happening at once. The first part of this document explains how to use locks in c++. Hopefully that will point you in the right direction.

http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~lavender/courses/cs371/lectures/lecture-10.pdf